# How do I achieve copy/paste behavior both ways between Excel and a DataGridView component?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview, copy-paste

How do I accomplish being able to paste data from Excel into a DataGridView and vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here:

[DataGrid copy/paste from Excel](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/103449-datagrid-copy-paste-excel)

[DataGridView Copy and Paste](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/DataGridViewCopyPaste.aspx)